# Convert unicode characters to floats Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a following code written in Python 3.6:

```
u"\u2500" * 4
```

which gives me "────"

However, when I run my code in Python 2.7.15, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

It seems that the integer 4 has become a float (4.0). Why is this happening?

I tried this and it worked:

```
 u"\u2500" * int(4)
```

Can anyone explain to me why is the integer converting to float?
And is converting back to int the right way to fix my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you run `u"\u2500" * 4.0` and not `u"\u2500" * 4`. And then the error is obvious.
So you should recheck your code **before** that call. Problem seems not here, but somewhere higher.

You always can open your console and check behavior like this.

```
etoneja@ois ~ $ python2
Python 2.7.18rc1 (default, Apr  7 2020, 12:05:55)
>>> u"\u2500" * 4
u'\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500'
>>> print u"\u2500" * 4
────
>>> print u"\u2500" * 4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```